# Package to enumerate all regular triangulations for point configuration

Tags: computational-geometry, combinatorial-geometry, triangulation

I am trying to enumerate the regular triangulation of some point configurations. The sage-math can enumerate all triangulations, but cannot check if each one is regular or not.

It seems TOPCOM can check the regularity. But I cannot even install TOPCOM. When I run the command "sage -i topcom" in the terminal, it returns: "sorry, this binary distribution does not support installing sage packages.If topcom is available from pipit you may install it by running %pip install topcom from the sage prompt."

If I run "pip install topcom", it returns: " Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement topcom; No matching distribution found for topcom".

Is there any other package that can check regularity? Or, is there an easy way to install TOPCOM?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are on some Debian-based distro and want to install some version of TOPCOM, say v1.1.2, you can proceed as follows:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y build-essential wget libgmp-dev libcdd-dev m4
$ mkdir topcom && cd topcom && mkdir source && mkdir install
$ cd install && export topcompath=$PWD && cd ..
$ cd source && wget https://www.wm.uni-bayreuth.de/de/team/rambau_joerg/TOPCOM-Downloads/TOPCOM-1_1_2.tgz
$ tar -xzf TOPCOM-1_1_2.tgz && cd topcom-1.1.2
$ ./configure --prefix=$topcompath && make -j4 && make install
```

Modify the above code as per your OS/distro, and use a suitable package manager for installing the relevant dependencies accordingly.

Use the command `points2alltriangs` or `points2placingtriang` with the `--regular` flag for finding all the regular triangulations.